# Kreysig Section 2.5 Question 8

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Corollary: A continuous mapping $T$ of a compact subset $M$ of a metric space $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$ assumes a maximum and a minimum at some points of $M$.

I was asked to use this corollary to prove that there is an $a>0$ such that $$a||x||_2\leq ||x||$$ where $||x||_2 =(|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+...+|x_n|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $||x||$ is any norm on the vector space $X$.

Is there any hint of this question? I totally do not know how to link the corollary to the question.

Comment: Is $X$ finite-dimensional? What are $x_1,\ldots,x_n$? Note that on an arbitrary vector space you don't have natural components. BTW, this is not really functional analysis but linear algebra.

Comment: the question doesn't mention that $X$ is finite or not. Note that $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and the norm defined respectively as above.

Comment: You just don't get my question. In an arbitrary vector space you cannot write $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. It's not possible!

Answer (score 1):

I guess $X = \mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$. Let $x$ be any non-zero vector. Then there is a vector $u$ with $\|u\|_2=1$ such that $x = cu$ for some $c$ (namely $u = \frac{x}{\|x\|_2}$ and $c = \|x\|_2$). Hence,
$$
\frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|_2} = \frac{\|cu\|}{\|cu\|_2} = \frac{|c|\|u\|}{|c|\|u\|_2} = \|u\|.
$$
So, we only have to minimize the function $f(u) = \|u\|$ on the compact set $\{x : \|x\|_2=1\}$. Is that function continuous on $X$? If so, you're obviously done. Can you prove it?

Comment: I can prove if $\{x:||x||_2=1\}$ is a vector subspace. But $\{x:||x||_2=1\}$ is not a vector subspace of $X$

Comment: ??? You are done if you can prove that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^n$ because then also its restriction to $\{x : \|x\|_2=1\}$ is continuous,

Comment: Oh I see, I have forgotten that restriction is also continuous if $f$ is continuous. Then everything solved. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First show that there is a $b\gt 0$ such that $$\|x\|\leq b\|x\|_2\tag1$$ for all $x\in X$.

After that, consider the unit sphere $S=\{x\in X: \|x\|_2=1\}$, which is compact(why?). Define $f:S\to \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=\|x\|$. Verify that $f$ is continuous and positive(you may need to use $(1)$). So by the above corollary, there is a real number $a\gt0$ satisfying $f(x)\geq a$ for all $x\in S$.

Comment: How does it help to prove the existence of $b$? And BTW, it's the same problem to show that.

Comment: You're right because $\|\cdot\|_2$ is a special norm. I would choose $b = (\sum_i\|e_i\|^2)^{1/2}$, by the way. ;-) IMHO you should mention that that continuity of $f$ follows from there.